# Issue with direct edit item link via email not closing

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, infopath

I have a very simple workflow sending an email for users to take a survey.  I do not want them to have to click on Edit Item, so I am trying to send a link directly to the edit view.  When I do so, the form will not close...it just hangs there.  It does submit data however.

I have used CurrentItemURL, that is not what I want since it is not in edit mode, though the editing works fine when used.  Currently, I am simply taking the edit URL and generating the ID within the link.

My issue has to be in the link.  I am using a custom form from InfoPath as well.

Current Link Example: https://[site path]/Lists/[list name]/Item/editifs.aspx?List=303173b5%2Dcaca%2D43c0%2Dbcb9%2D4857e9533757&ID=**[%Current Item ID%]**&IsDlg=1&Web=cab0601f%2D6c08%2D4f11%2Db11c%2Dcc9dd7b11d2d